# SQL CASE statement with boolean operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

See statement:

```
SELECT      t1.region, 
            Count(t1.orders) AS orders, 
            CASE t1.week 
                      WHEN < '5' THEN 'APR' 
                      WHEN < '10' THEN 'MAY' 
                      WHEN < '14' THEN 'JUN' 
                      WHEN < '19' THEN 'JUL' 
                      WHEN < '23' THEN 'AUG' 
                      WHEN < '27' THEN 'SEP' 
                      WHEN < '32' THEN 'OCT' 
                      WHEN < '36' THEN 'NOV' 
                      WHEN < '40' THEN 'DEC' 
                      WHEN < '45' THEN 'JAN' 
                      WHEN < '49' THEN 'FEB' 
                      WHEN < '53' THEN 'MAR' 
            END AS month, 
            dbo.inf_dates.months

FROM        dbo.[NonVoice Weekly_InflowCOMCAN] AS t1 
INNER JOIN  dbo.inf_dates 
                ON t1.week = dbo.inf_dates.fin_wk

WHERE       notes = 'Weekly COMPLETED'
            AND ([2MB/sub]) = 'ETH' 
            AND dbo.inf_dates.date > CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-03 00:00:00', 102)

GROUP BY   t1.region 
           ,dbo.inf_dates.months
```

As you can see I am trying to group rows with months instead of the weeks that I have in my table by creating a month column and grouping the weeks together. When I do a case statement like `CASE WHEN t1.Week < '5' THEN 'APR'` I get the right results but it forces me to group by weeks which is not what I want. The two months column in the table are different by the way.

Comment: You need to group by case statement. Just copy case statement into grouping section.

Comment: is the code correct though on the case statement?

Comment: I hope you do know that month borders do not align with week borders: a week may be in two different months. Plus it shifts slightly over the years.

Comment: Try to format your code to make it more easily readable, it'll help you get more answers.

Comment: You have to be carefull when comparing strings. It compares them character by character. For example, what do you assume the result of this query will be : `select case when '10' < '5' then 'smaller' else 'equal or bigger' end`. So you should compare the casted or converted to int values.

Comment: You had `dbo.inf_dates`, then add new column `MonthName` to it. You don't need any `case ...` at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right format, also comparing `varchar` with the `<` symbol is quite odd,
maybe you will have to cast your weeks into integers first.
By the way, what if the week is over or equal than 53 ??

Also, you better use a corresponding table rather than hardcode the cases.

```
SELECT      t1.region, 
            Count(t1.orders) AS orders, 
            CASE 
                  WHEN t1.week < 5 THEN 'APR'
                  WHEN t1.week < 10 THEN 'MAY'
                  WHEN t1.week < 14 THEN 'JUN' 
                  WHEN t1.week < 19 THEN 'JUL' 
                  WHEN t1.week < 23 THEN 'AUG' 
                  WHEN t1.week < 27 THEN 'SEP' 
                  WHEN t1.week < 32 THEN 'OCT' 
                  WHEN t1.week < 36 THEN 'NOV' 
                  WHEN t1.week < 40 THEN 'DEC' 
                  WHEN t1.week < 45 THEN 'JAN' 
                  WHEN t1.week < 49 THEN 'FEB' 
                  WHEN t1.week < 53 THEN 'MAR' 
                  ELSE 'DEFAULT VALUE'
            END AS month, 
            dbo.inf_dates.months

FROM        dbo.[NonVoice Weekly_InflowCOMCAN] AS t1 
            INNER JOIN dbo.inf_dates 
                ON t1.week = dbo.inf_dates.fin_wk

WHERE       notes = 'Weekly COMPLETED'
            AND [2MB/sub]) = 'ETH' 
            AND dbo.inf_dates.date > CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-03 00:00:00', 102)

GROUP BY   t1.region 
           ,dbo.inf_dates.months
```